# Transforming Data in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am importing an excel sheet into a Dataframe. When call dtypes in python I get the column as an Object.

I am turning it to float with a function and then .apply()

When I do a

```
df.groupby(['A'])['B'].sum()
```

I get this error:

```
 unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

I´ve checked the excel sheet and there are only numbers. How can I transform this data into integer or ignore the values that python can´t transform?

There are `Nan` values in this column.

Comment: `df.astype(float).grouby(by=['A']).sum()`

Comment: This solution is not working. I am doing this: df_estoque_atraso_1.astype(float).grouby(by=['Num. Pedido']).sum() and getting this: TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [float64]